# Where to find Time(CPU) column in VisualVM?

Tags: java, time, profiling, cpu, visualvm

I'm profiling my application with VisualVM 1.3.3

It seems to me that both snapshots "Hot Spots" and "Call Tree" show the wall-clock time. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491340/what-the-difference-between-time-and-timecpu-in-visualvm) the questioner mentions CPU time indicated in Time(CPU) column.

But I can't find that column Time(CPU). Can you help with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Time(CPU) is available in 'Sampler' tab.